# Is there a way to access a CSV file and edit it dynamically?

Tags: php

Is there any method that allows a person to select a .csv file through an `input` with type=file and than he can edit or update his csv file?

Just like when we open a .docx file in hotmail and ms word gets opened on left side. Or like when we select a photo on facebook we can edit it.

Is there any similar method to edit csv file on php?

Comment: _edit csv file on php_ ? PHP is a programming language not an editor

Comment: hotmail - giggle. but if csv is associated with a local editor it should be the same, but this has nothing to do with php

Comment: You narrowed down the whole perspective... well. My point of this question is accessibility.

Comment: i'm not sure we really get your point(question).

Comment: PHP's user Interface is (normally) the browser. If you want to edit a csv file send it to the browser and write/borrow some javascript to edit the text in a csv way, or just allow the user to edit a `textarea`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like phpmyadmin but for CSV file.

a google search lead me to http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5594-PHP-Manage-CSV-files-like-database-tables.html

hope it is useful